# How to align a 2d array with an array of strings on top and on the side of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, console, text-alignment

I have this 2d array im trying to print with names of usa states on top and on the left of the array:

prints like this:

[image]

I have this method for printing

```cs
public void ShowArray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("\t" + v[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.Write(v[i] + "\t");

        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i,j]+ "\t");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PadRight/PadLeft FTW:

```cs
private static string[] v = new string[] { "Maine", "California", "Texas" };
private static string[,] array = new string[,]
{
    { "0", "90", "0" },
    { "90", "0", "100" },
    { "0", "0", "0" },
};

public static void ShowArray()
{
    var maxLength = v.Max(s => s.Length); // <- NEW

    for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("\t" + v[i].PadLeft(maxLength));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.Write(v[i].PadRight(maxLength) + "\t");

        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i, j].PadRight(maxLength) + "\t");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

output:

```sh
             Maine      California           Texas
Maine           0               90              0
California      90              0               100
Texas           0               0               0
```